# In ADT unfortunately 'application name ' has stopped

Tags: android, runtime-error

my code is activity_show_location.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="@string/lat"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/unkwn"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="@string/lon"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/unkwn"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ShowLocationActivity.java

```
    public class ShowLocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    private TextView latitudeField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_location);
         latitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
         longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        Activity a;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Location location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                if (location != null) {
                    System.out.println("Provider " + provider
                            + " has been selected.");
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                } else {
                    latitudeField.setText("Location not available.");
                    longitudeField.setText("Location not available.");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { // TODO
                                                                                // Auto-generated
                                                                                // method
                                                                                // stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // Inflate the menu; this
                                                    // adds items to the action
                                                    // bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_show_location, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I am run in ADT eclipse logcat shows

This is my LogCat shows:

```
03-20 07:44:56.383: W/Trace(871): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 
03-20 07:44:56.383: W/Trace(871): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 
03-20 07:44:56.783: W/Trace(871): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 
03-20 07:44:56.783: W/Trace(871): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 
03-20 07:44:57.343: D/AndroidRuntime(871): Shutting down VM 
03-20 07:44:57.343: W/dalvikvm(871): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.locationapi/com.example.locationapi.ShowLocationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.location.LocationManager.checkProvider(LocationManager.java:1594) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1138) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at com.example.locationapi.ShowLocationActivity.onCreate(ShowLocationActivity.java:32) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  ... 11 more 
03-20 07:45:39.193: I/Process(871): Sending signal. PID: 871 SIG: 9
```

And i got when emulator is run as "unfortunately LocationAPI, has stopped." please tell the solution.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null

Comment: can u modify the code  to run as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the log here is the debug

```
07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871): at android.location.LocationManager.checkProvider(LocationManager.java:1594)
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871): at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1138) 
03-20 07:44:57.373: E/AndroidRuntime(871): at com.example.locationapi.ShowLocationActivity.onCreate(ShowLocationActivity.java:32)
```

So at `ShowLocationActivity.java:32`

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

you provide the `provider` which is basically null. So you might need to check what could be possible cause of it being null.

here is list of items you should check:

1. Is it due to thread?
2. Was is ever assigned?
3. Try giving it a default value.

Also you should not touch your UI thread from your sub threads. So doing

```
latitudeField.setText("Location not available.");
longitudeField.setText("Location not available.");
```

is also not good idea.

Try using `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

I guss that you are not passing the location in your emulator, to test gps locations in emulator you need to pass the values using DDMS

Here is how u do that:

1. open DDMS prespective in eclipse:
2. Go to emulator Controle
3. In location controles manual tab give lang and lat values and press send button, then start the application.

Let me know if it works

Comment: same problem occur "unfortunately, appname has stopped."